# SOAP and PHP and WSDL Request

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm trying to get some info out of WSDL using SOAP and PHP

I have these elements:

```
     <s:element name="GetVersion">
        <s:complexType>
           <s:sequence/>
        </s:complexType>
     </s:element>
     <s:element name="GetVersionResponse">
        <s:complexType>
           <s:sequence>
              <s:element name="ApplicationVersion" type="s:string"/>
              <s:element name="CgiVersion" type="s:string"/>
              <s:element name="SiteName" type="s:string"/>
           </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
     </s:element>
```

I understand how to retrieve the data if the element sequence has a complex type, but this one doesn't seem to have one.

I ran the WSDL through SOAP UI and when you run the request for "GetVersion" you get a response and it returns the app version, the cgi version and the sitename.

How do i construct my request to return the same data in PHP?

Comment: Can you just show the request as you can see in SoapUI?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know:

Complex Types are Array's / Objects in php

So define an array or object having the properties you describe and return it **within your PHP Soap Server implentation**

```
function getVersion(){
$array['appversion'] = 1;
$array['cgiversion'] = 2;
$array['sitename'] = "test";
return $array;
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.soapserver.php